# how to parse a URL parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, how can I get the parameters of a URL string (not the current URL)?

```
http://localhost:8080/feasthunt/changePassword.html?TOKEN=0FA3267F-0C62-B1C9-DB71-76F6829671ED
```

can i get token in JSON object?

Comment: Why would you want it in a "JSON object"? It's a single value.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a 'JSON' object, and just use split to grab it, since its after a '='

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8080/feasthunt/changePassword.html?     TOKEN=0FA3267F-0C62-B1C9-DB71-76F6829671ED';
var token = url.split('=').pop(); 

//token is equal to: "0FA3267F-0C62-B1C9-DB71-76F6829671ED"
```

https://jsbin.com/siyazo/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var str = "http://localhost:8080/feasthunt/changePassword.html?TOKEN=0FA3267F-0C62-B1C9-DB71-76F6829671ED";
var tokenValue = str.substring(str.indexOf("?")+1).split("=")[1];
```

Or more generic

```
var paramMap = {}; str.substring(str.indexOf("?")+1).split("&").forEach(function(val){
  var param = val.split("=");
  paramMap[param[0]] = param[1];
})
```

`paramMap` is your JSON object, where `paramMap["TOKEN"]` will give you the value for this param